# Inheritance of operators in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, assignment-operator

I have read many similar questions on this site, but nothing that answers what I am trying to do.

```
public class base {
public:
    base(){
        //Default Constructor
    }

    base( int num ){
        // use num to create base
    }

    base& operator=( base&& _data ){
        // do move assignment stuff
    }
};

public class derived : public base {
public:
    derived() : base() {
        int num1;
        //Do some stuff

        // Now I want to assign the base of this class with a new base
        base::operator=( Base( num1 ) );
    }
};
```

I would like to call the move assignment ( or just regular assignment ) on the base class during the derived class's construction. This way that the derived class can parse some information before it creates its base. This just doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work." Also, why would you want to do such a thing? Just construct `base` directly with the right number.

Comment: @Barry: from the looks of it, the number is probably not known yet when the `base` constructor is called, so it cannot be passed in the constructor parameter.

Comment: I assume by `Base(num1)` you mean `base(num1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the base class is initialized *before* the constructor body is entered. Thus with your approach you first initialize `base` and then overwrite it through the assignment. That's not good.

Use a delegating constructor and a private helper function:

```
class derived : public base {
private:
    static int help () { /* Do some stuff */ }

    // private constructor to be called with the helper values
    derived (int i) : base (i) { }
public:
    derived() : derived (help ()) { }
};
```

Of course, in this case, you could just define your constructor by

```
derived () : base (help ()) { }
```

Yet the delegating constructor approach above becomes useful if you have to calculate more than one argument value for the base class constructor:

```
class base {
public:
    base (int i, double d);
};

class derived : public base {
private:
    struct BaseParams { int i; double d; };
    static BaseParams help () {
        BaseParams p;
        /* Do some stuff and set p.i and p.d */;
        return p;
    }

    // private constructor to be called with the helper values
    derived (BaseParams const & p) : base (p.i, p.d) { }
public:
    derived() : derived (help ()) { }
};
```

If you really want to construct a `base` object and move it in, use base's move constructor:

```
class base {
public:
    base (int i, double d);
    base (base &&);
};

class derived : public base {
private:
    static base help () {
        /* Do some stuff and finally construct a base object */;
        return base { /* calculated parameters for constructor of base */ };
    }

    // private constructor to be called with a base object to move from
    derived (base && b) : base (std::move (b)) { }
public:
    derived() : derived (help ()) { }
    // or simply derived () : base (help ()) { }
};
```